# How do I redirect/rewrite to the FQDN URL without setting ServerName?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, hostname, fqdn

Often in intranets, users will direct URLs to a hostname without supplying the FQDN. Example:

```
http://internalHost
```

Instead of

```
http://internalHost.example.com
```

I would like to redirect users / rewrite URLs so that everything will use the FQDN. Here's the catch: I don't want to set ServerName explicitly. (This is for a product which will be deployed in multiple intranets so we can't know the value of ServerName ahead of time).

According to: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotDetermineServerName Apache uses a reverse lookup to determine a default FQDN.

How can I make use of/reference that FQDN that Apache is using for a mod_rewrite or redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you read about UseCanonicalName.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname

Probably the option

```
UseCanonicalName DNS
```

Should be sufficient (as Apache will by itself already generate a redirect)

De documentation also mentions that UseCanonicalName influences what ends up in the SERVER_NAME variable name, which you could use in a rewriterule.